# Why java code with infinite while loop with 4 minutes of sleep not executing in windows?

Tags: java

I want to check for some condition after every 4 minutes. If specified condition occurred I want to close firefox and restart it using batch script in windows 7. I created runnable jar of following code and run that with javaw but it is not working even if that condition occur. Same code worked in eclipse.

```
class WebAlert {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebAlert w = new WebAlert();
    while(true) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(240000);
            w.sendPost();
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
private void sendPost() {
    if(somecondition){
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "restartFirefox.bat");
        File dir = new File("C:\\");
        pb.directory(dir);
        pb.start();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: How did you create the runnable jar file?

Comment: @preciousbetine in eclipse with export option

Answer (score 0):

Please set the directory to the batchfile path and use ProcessBuilder to pass the necessary argument.

```
File dir = new File("C:\\path_to_the_batchfile\\");

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/C", "Start", "restartFirefox.bat");
pb.directory(dir);
pb.start();
```